# rearrange rows values in csv using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I am working with pandas and have a csv file that looks like this

```
  ID                Name        Store      Price           
Melbourne           
    1               aaaa        bbbb        570
    2               cccc        dddd        236
    3               eeee        ffff        230
Sydney
    1               hhhh        gggg        2300
    2               kkkk        llll        266
```

I want the it in this shape

```
City            ID               Name        Store       Price      
Melbourne        1               aaaa        bbbb        570
Melbourne        2               cccc        dddd        236
Melbourne        3               eeee        ffff        230
Sydney           1               hhhh        gggg        23
Sydney           2               kkkk        llll        266
```

What I am thinking is 
1. adding a new column

```
  ID        New               Name        Store      Price           
Melbourne   NaN  
    1       NaN               aaaa        bbbb        570
    2       NaN               cccc        dddd        236
    3       NaN               eeee        ffff        230
Sydney 
    1       NaN               hhhh        gggg        2300
    2       NaN               kkkk        llll        266
```

2. then change the index to ID. So it would look like this

   ```
     ID       New      Name        Store      Price           
    Melbourne NaN  
    1         NaN      aaaa        bbbb        570
    2         NaN      cccc        dddd        236
    3         NaN      eeee        ffff        230
    Sydney    NaN
    1         NaN      hhhh        gggg        2300
    2         NaN      kkkk        llll        266
   ```
3. and then something like this

   ```
     ID         New              Name        Store      Price           
    Melbourne   NaN  
    Melbourne    1               aaaa        bbbb        570
    Melbourne    2               cccc        dddd        236
    Melbourne    3               eeee        ffff        230
    Sydney       NaN
    Sydney       1               hhhh        gggg        2300
    Sydney       2               kkkk        llll        266
   ```
4. Finally change the column name and delete the rows without values

   ```
   City            ID              Name        Store      Price           
   Melbourne       1               aaaa        bbbb        570
   Melbourne       2               cccc        dddd        236
   Melbourne       3               eeee        ffff        230
   Sydney          1               hhhh        gggg        2300
   Sydney          2               kkkk        llll        266
   ```

   I am not sure if it can be implemented or not. Please give me some idea about how can I implement this.

Comment: can you not use something like remove index? or index based on ID column?

Comment: I have edited the question. In step 2 I have edited and changed the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this and below are some ideas on how to implement your proposed method.

**Step 1:**

Check if a string only contains alphabetic characters by using `str.isalpha()` method:

```
df["column"].apply(lambda x: x if x.isalpha() else None)
```

Above will return a `Series` with the numeric values in your `ID` column as None. You can store this in a new column.

This solution assumes that every `x` is a string.

---

If you don't know for sure that all the numbers in your column are strings you could create a list of cities:

```
my_cities = ['Melbourne', 'Sydney']
```

Then check if the value in your column is a city and store it in a boolean `Series`:

```
is_city = df['column'].isin(my_cities)
```

Apply the `Series` as a mask, and replace values with `None`:

```
df.loc[~is_city, 'column'] = None
```

(Note that `~` means "not" so this would return rows where value "is not a city").

**Step 2:**

Fill the new column using `ffill` method:

```
df["new_column"].fillna(method="ffill")
```

`ffill` basically does step 3 in your question. You can read about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna).

**Step 3:**

Finally drop all rows containing at least one `None`:

```
df.dropna()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
It worked with a little changes like i had to use x.isdigit() funciton to check the digit and to drop the rows I had use df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True) as suggested by @Abhi in the other answer.